Is it okay to have two separate interactions with the same variable in one model?
My main model is this:
model <- brm(
  bf(binary ~ categorical1 + categorical2 + (1 | id) + (1 | country)),
  data = data,
  family = bernoulli(link = "logit"),
  prior = priors,
  chains = 8, iter = 2000, seed = 345)

Now as an exploratory analysis I want to test the interaction between country and each categorical variables, but I am not interested in the interaction between categorical1 and categorical2.
I wonder if this model is overfitting, and should I run two separate models? How can I determine that?
model <- brm(
  bf(binary ~ categorical1 * country + categorical2 * country + (1 | id)),
  data = data,
  family = bernoulli(link = "logit"),
  prior = priors,
  chains = 8, iter = 2000, seed = 345)


In theory, there should be no problem with this. It's possible that it's overfit, but this depends on your data - you can use information criteria or other model comparison techniques to evaluate if it's overfit. But it's absolutely valid to include two interactions with the same variable.
You should consider whether you want country to be an independent fixed effect or a random effect like you specified in the first model. You could do something like this if your data structure allows:
model <- brm(
  bf(binary ~ categorical1 + categorical2 + (1 | id) + (1 + categorical1 + categorical2 | country)),
  data = data,
  family = bernoulli(link = "logit"),
  prior = priors,
  chains = 8, iter = 2000, seed = 345)

